# Max_bars_back error only in real time bars

Tags: pine-script

I have made a scipt that auto-detects market structures, it works fine on hystoric bars.
But when the current candle (real time candle) closes and a new candle is generated, then the "max_bars_back" indicator error occures.

I have already tried to use the max_bars_back() function in every custom function I have coded by applying it on every output variable but this doesn't work either.

My code only plots several lines onto the chart using line.new()

Answer (score 0):

If your code is using the bar_index in-built during calculations, remember that you need to specify the buffer size using max_bars_back(time,).

Comment: commnet on code block